# How do you calculate the total number of -1s and the total numbers of 1s in the table? (c++)

Tags: c++

Here is the coding below :) I have also commented on some parts so that it is easier to understand the output of the code.

I have a slight idea that I need to use an "if statement" with "rand()%" in order to make sure that the program knows we want to calculate the sum of 1s and -1s only. for e.g using "rand()%2-1" can help with getting the total sum of 1s outputted in the table. Again, I'm not sure if this idea will work or not.

So the program should output something like "The amount of 1s in the table is 5 and the amount of -1s in the table is 3" for the first time its ran. Then when it is ran the second time, it could output something like "The amount of 1s in the table is 2 and the amount is -1s in the table is 5"

Sorry for any confusions and All your help will be highly appreciated :) :)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<ctime>


 using namespace std;

 int main() {
srand(time(0));
const int ROWS=3;
const int COLS=4;

int table[ROWS][COLS];

for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i ++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)   {
        table[i][j] = rand()%3-1;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i ++)  {
    for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
        cout << setw(3) << table[i][j];

    cout << endl;
 }



bool checkTable [ROWS][COLS];

for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i ++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)   {
        if (table[i][j] !=0) {
 checkTable[i][j] = true;
   } 
  else{
 checkTable[i][j] = false;
   }


     //The output in the line below is the final line outputted by the 
     console. This prints out "1" if there is a value in the index within 
     the table provided above (the value is represented by 1 or -1), and 
     prints out "0" if there is no value in the index (represented by 0) 

  cout << " " << checkTable[i][j];  



    }
}

return 0;
 }
```

Comment: why `rand()` ?? what has counting the number of 1s in a table to do with random numbers? Once you filled it you dont need any `rand()`

Comment: The "rand()" is used in this coding to make the task more challenging aha. There is a given range which is -1 to 0 (this prints out -1, 0 and 1 within the table).  Each time the program is run, the three numbers are outputted in different order through the "rand()".  The tricky bit is to figure out how to calculate the amount of 1's and -1's  that are outputted within the table each time the program is run. And every time there will be a different total due to the "rand()" function.   I have edited my question above just now to clarify it

Comment: please try to clarify the question. It is not clear why you think you need `rand()` for counting. Also I dont find the code where you do any counting. No offense, but your code seems to be unrelated to your task "count occurences of 1s"

Comment: what is tricky about it? Simply add something like `if (value == 1) { numberOfOnes++; }`

Comment: Sorry for any confusions within the code. I used the "rand()" just to make the coding a little bit interesting

Answer (score 1):

> [...] for e.g using "rand()%2-1" can help with getting the total sum of 1s
>   outputted in the table.

I dont really understand what you mean by that. Counting and randomness dont go well together. I mean of course you can fill a matrix with random numbers and **then** do some counting, but `rand()` wont help anything for the counting.

You need something as simple as that:

```
 int main() {
srand(time(0));
const int ROWS=3;
const int COLS=4;

int table[ROWS][COLS];

for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i ++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)   {
        table[i][j] = rand()%3-1;
    }
}

unsigned ones_counter = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i ++)  {
    for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {               // dont forget the bracket
        cout << setw(3) << table[i][j];
        if (table[i][j] == 1) { ones_counter++;}   // <- this is counting
    }
    cout << endl;
}

std::cout << "number of 1s in the table : " << ones_counter << "\n";
....
```

Comment: Yes aha I understand they don't...but it's a task which was provided to me by my tutor. Thanks for the help :)